# Encoded path is encoded again

Tags: karate

I have to make a request:

```
* url foo
* path bar
* path code
```

Code is retrieved from another request and I receive it url encoded. 
The problem is when I put it in the path, karate encode it again.

Ex: I receive `zxc1J%2BV%2FMnb` and in path it becomes `zxc1J%252BV%252FMnb`.
`%2B`is replaced by `%252B`.

When I decode received code and put it in path, it is not encoded.

My javascript function to decode is :
`* def codeDecoded = decodeURIComponent(code)`

and encoding function is `* def codeEncoded = encodeURIComponent(codeDecoded)`

Am I missing smth? What is wrong? How can I manage this? Thanks.

Edit:

@Peter Thomas I try my last chance, because I already showed the prb to someone from server and he didn't understand why karate encodes again smth already encoded and doesn't encode smth decoded.

So my first request is a POST request, which returns an encoded code in responseHeaders. Ex:  `GVkX1%2FKZEi%2FWQ`.

In my second request I have to take this code and put it in the path ex: `url/GVkX1%2FKZEi%2FWQ`. 
The problem is that karate transforms it to `url/GVkX1%252FKZEi%252FWQ` . And I don't need it. And if I decode `url/GVkX1%2FKZEi%2FWQ` before to put it in path, the url in karate is `url/GVkX1/KZEi/WQ`. When put in path, the decoded code is not encoded in karate. I hope it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Karate will always encode the `path` you provide for your convenience. This is what 99% of users expect anyways.

There is nothing wrong with using a custom function to decode and ensure you pass un-encoded URL / path values to Karate, so by all means, please continue to do so !

Edit: quite likely the way you tried to decode may be wrong, try this:

```
* def encoded = 'zxc1J%2BV%2FMnb'
* def decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encoded, 'UTF-8')
* print decoded
```

Which prints:

```
[print] zxc1J+V/Mnb
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. The prb is that karate encodes what is already encoded. And if I decode and put a decoded code in the path, karate does not encode it. I don't understand why. When I nedd encoding it does not do it. And when I do not need it, it encodes. How I can manage this?

Comment: @nirind you said you are using `* def codeDecoded = decodeURIComponent(code)` to decode. so just decode before giving it to Karate.

Comment: thanks. The problem is not in decoding, both of method work: with `* def decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encoded, 'UTF-8')` or `* def codeDecoded = decodeURIComponent(code)`. The problem is that karate does not encode the decoded code. Ex: decoded `zxc1J+V/Mnb`is not encoded in path and is taken as `zxc1J+V/Mnb`

Comment: @nirind `+` and `/` are NOT valid URL characters and WILL be encoded, this is the correct behavior. you are probably confused because some browsers don't. the main thing is - when the path is sent as `zxc1J%2BV%2FMnb` is the server responding correctly ? then there is nothing more to do. I just checked in a test to validate this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/5c498ae7964ce34734cdd68601226cbb00e2b655

Comment: @nirind I can't help you any more with the info you have provided. it is possible your server is behaving wrongly. also watch out for the `/` character - it becomes a path delimiter, it is easy to make a mistake if you are not careful. BTW I had a mistake in my prev commit, here is the updated example. note how I had to take into account the path: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/0d4927b5d8af3fb6527dd04916b828ae2d3faaae - work with someone on the server team if needed.

Comment: @nirind no, I find your updated description extremely confusing. ask some stranger near to you to read it and tell you what they understood - then you will understand :) try harder please. suggestion: instead of `path` try to put everything in the `url`. also please look at the git commit I posted above and understand how the path may have to be adjusted. ALL THE BEST.

Comment: I put everything in url as here `* url foo + receivedCode` and it works. But I find it illogic and not elegant. It should be ` * url foo` ` * path receivedCode`